# url decode for unicode

Tags: unicode, utf-8

How can I decode unicode characters from an URL?. I specified `response.charset="UTF-8"` in my request, and I received unicode characters like `%e3%81%a4%e3%82%8c%e3%`. How can I convert these to something I can display on my form?

Comment: 'Decode Unicode Font'? Perhaps you could explain what you mean?

Comment: Sorry,my letter is not completed. Please, check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515223/how-to-decode-url-for-unicode-font

Answer (score 1):

[RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) specifies how to interpret this. You first decode the percent-escaped byte values in the standard way. Then you interpret the byte stream as UTF-8 to reconstruct the characters. You can find more information [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).