# how to decode url for unicode font

Tags: unicode, utf-8

I have been developing an asp application. I want to use response.charset that uses "UTF-8". I try to encode a unicode string by using server.urlencode. It is showed like this "%e3%81%a4%e3%82%". I got a problem this. I don't know how to decode url. Please, help me

Comment: Can you post original text of it. That might help in decoding it.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you, there is a tutorial and a tool that can decode the encoded URLs you can check it out [**here**](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm)